# iphone dev : deselect(or unhighlight) selected tab item

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'd like to deselect(or unhighlight) selected tab item.
I tried many things I can, but no luck.

My tab bar is wrapped by `UITabBarController` (say it as `tvc`).

First, I tried

```
tvc.selectedIndex = -1 or 0 or nil;
```

then nothing happened.

Second

```
tvc.tabBar.selectedItem = -1 or 0 or nil;
```

it crashed.

Is there any other way I can do?
Thanks in advance.

One more thing,
without `UITabBarController` (only with `UITabBar`),
by setting its selectedItem as nil, it `deselect(unhighlight)` selected item.
but with controller, no, failed.

Comment: That would be very bad UI design.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `selectedViewController` on the `UITabBarController` to `nil`. Not sure if it'll do what you need but under OS 3.0 the way tab controllers are managed have changed.